# How can I connect from `project` to `mysql` container in docker swarm?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-swarm

I am trying to deploy a stack with the docker swarm with the following configuration `docker-compose.yaml` file as below via the command:

```sh
docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c docker-compose.yaml project
```

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: project_production
      MYSQL_USER: username
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.13.4
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - internal
  website:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/project/project-website:latest
    networks:
      - internal
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=production
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysql
      - ES_HOST=http://es01
      - project_DATABASE_USERNAME=root
      - project_DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
    depends_on:
      - es01
      - mysql

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local
  mysql_data:

networks:
  internal:
    external: true
    name: project
```

Before I deploy the stack I also have created the network for the project via the following command:

```sh
docker network create -d overlay project
```

But when I see the logs for the `project` using `docker logs` command I see the following error stops my `project` get started:

```
Mysql2::Error: Host '10.0.2.202' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I went exactly as the documents suggested I am not sure what is wrong with the settings that I have come up!

#### Question:

How can I connect from `project` to `mysql` container in docker swarm?

Comment: Is there a reason you are creating the network externally first? Looks like its a prublic network and you are connecting to the wrong (`Myslq2`) instance. also your mysql usernames and passwords don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation, Docker Swarm automatically creates the overlay network for you. So I think you don't need to create an external network by default, unless you have specific needs:

> When you initialize a swarm or join a Docker host to an existing swarm, two new networks are created on that Docker host:
>
> - an overlay network called ingress, which handles the control and data traffic related to swarm services. When you create a swarm service and do not connect it to a user-defined overlay network, it connects to the ingress network by default.
> - a bridge network called docker_gwbridge, which connects the individual Docker daemon to the other daemons participating in the swarm.

As Chris also mentioned in the comments, the DB credentials also don't match.

OPTIONAL: `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST` is only necessary if you want to connect as `root` user which is not recommended in production environments. There's also no need to expose the port to the host machine since the database service will only be used from inside the cluster. So if you still want to use root user, you can set the variable to allow connections only from inside the cluster, like `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=10.*.*.*`.